# dl4j-0.0.3.3-examples compiling errors: can not find symbol while importing a class

Tags: java, deep-learning

i have compiled project nd4j, Canova and deeplearning4j successfully but errors occur while compiling [dl4j-0.0.3.3-examples](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4j), the following are the errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project deeplearning4j-examples: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/luolianhai/dl4j-0.0.3.3-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/deepbelief/DBNIrisExample.java:[22,49] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class GradientPlotterIterationListener
[ERROR] location: package org.deeplearning4j.plot.iterationlistener
[ERROR] /home/luolianhai/dl4j-0.0.3.3-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/deepbelief/DBNIrisExample.java:[23,49] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LossPlotterIterationListener
[ERROR] location: package org.deeplearning4j.plot.iterationlistener
```

Comment: please git clone the dl4j-{version}-examples repo. you can join us on Gitter if you have questions: gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some library (dependency) in the build configuration or skipping a package. Check if the library or package of GradientPlotterIterationListener is being included/excluded in the build configuration.

Comment: Thanks but how to check the build configuration?

Comment: In the pom.XML file do you know how to use maven?,  did you change something from the original sources? Did you check the folder of the classes?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've check the folder of the classes and there is no GradientPlotterIterationListener.class and LossPlotterIterationListener.class but why?

Comment: I've checked the online repo an seems like everything is fine and that I have to download these files to see if it happens to me but it will be in more than 12 hours, sorry. For now, you can checkout and try again and check if the examples project is using the last version of deeplearning, where the classes are present at least they exist in the repo

Comment: Check the POM to confirm where these examples are running from. If it has SNAPSHOT in the dl4j and nd4j then git clone those repositories and build locally. Otherwise use Maven Repo. I don't really know the difference between build locally and using Maven Repo. Further more, it do has SNAPSHOT in the dl4j and nd4j.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "checking where the classes are present at least they exist in the repo"?

Comment: I downloaded the source code for nd4j, Canova, deeplearning4j and dl4j-0.0.0.3-examples once again and compiled successfully this time.Thank you very much.

Comment: It was nothing. I was just iporting the projects into eclipse... what a heavy project... almost 2Gb.

Comment: What project? Project deeplearning4j is only 1.1Gb, not 2Gb in my computer. It seems that I had better find a way to synchronize the local files and the files in the github since I met many errors while compiling the old files.